# Tuning SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, database-tuning

We migrated from Oracle to SQL Server, the new server has good resources and should burn through data.

When reading OS MasterMap data it consumes over 50% of cpu and takes several minutes to load.

I have run ANALYZE and INDEX on the three databases.

```
SELECT    latch_class,   waiting_requests_count , wait_time_ms, max_wait_time_ms          --- *
FROM sys.dm_os_latch_stats
WHERE waiting_requests_count > 100
ORDER BY  waiting_requests_count DESC
```

```
latch_class waiting_requests_count  wait_time_ms    max_wait_time_ms
BUFFER  81551206    81704580    2017
ACCESS_METHODS_DATASET_PARENT   1641537 5663549 7506
NESTING_TRANSACTION_READONLY    1084221 494094  213
DBCC_CHECK_AGGREGATE    431924  120721  64
FGCB_ADD_REMOVE 167166  2130810 806
NESTING_TRANSACTION_FULL    91970   23584   194
ACCESS_METHODS_BULK_ALLOC   25362   493780  995
```

```sql
SELECT  wait_type, signal_wait_time_ms , waiting_tasks_count
FROM sys.dm_os_wait_stats
WHERE signal_wait_time_ms > 176397
ORDER BY waiting_tasks_count DESC
```

The results:

```
wait_type   signal_wait_time_ms waiting_tasks_count
SLEEP_TASK  2002394 76078204
PAGEIOLATCH_SH  277602  67814336
SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD 7501348 66782317
LOGMGR_QUEUE    523607  54389813
DIRTY_PAGE_POLL 187977  44182775
CXPACKET    5480362 27547323
ASYNC_NETWORK_IO    720221  20290395
LAZYWRITER_SLEEP    1119484 14749937
WRITELOG    685367  14323568
HADR_FILESTREAM_IOMGR_IOCOMPLETION  176407  9559003
BACKUPBUFFER    564488  9513327
SLEEP_BPOOL_FLUSH   252249  8582959
CLR_MANUAL_EVENT    2000281 7383128
SP_SERVER_DIAGNOSTICS_SLEEP 9665265581  5643767
```

Comment: The database is approx 1 - 2 GB. It is currently running on Oracle (with 2 cores), don't experience the issues running on SQL Server with over 16 cores + approx 7GB RAM

Comment: Please check Brenz's [advice for SQL Server slowness](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/03/getting-help-with-a-slow-query/) troubleshooting. A query plan, hardware description, DDL statements would be useful. Please edit the question and add those into the question body. Do not add details as comments, those are hard to read.